# Training an Auto Encoder results in average output

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders

I am using an autoencoder in order to compress ECG data. I have implemented it according to the tutorial available at http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial. I have validated the implementation using the MNIST dataset and it works quite well (as far as I can tell the results are plausible).

So now I am using the same approach to train an autoencoder on intervals of ECG data and the output I get is always the average of the data (e.g. a straight line over the entire interval). I have tried different interval sizes and, different hidden layer sizes as well as different parameters for sparsity and learning rate, however, the result is always the same. Even if I set sparsity penalty to 0, it is not learning the identity mapping for the same number of hidden units as input units.

Anyone got a hint in which direction I should look for my mistake?

Thanks a bunch!

Edit: My training data set is about 50.000 intervals if I split them into 8 sec. pieces, represented by 400 samples each.

Comment: What reconstruction error are you using?

Comment: Average half squared error plus sparsity and weight penalty terms.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I had an error in my implementation. With nowadays tools (pytorch, tensorflow, ...) this shouldn't be an issue anymore, though.